# use a variable in the table name when renaming a table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to rename a table in SQL Server 2008 R2 using the code below;

```
declare @date varchar(8)
set @date = convert( varchar(8), getdate(), 112)

exec sp_rename 'LM_SM_Billing_and_Send_Data', 'LM_SM_Billing_and_Send_Data_@date'
```

My intention is to rename the table with the current date appended.

```
select convert( varchar(8), getdate(), 112)
```

returns 20141219

but when I run the rename it names the table;

```
LM_SM_Billing_and_Send_Data_@date
```

instead of inserting the date

I'm wondering if it is possible to have it rename to;

```
LM_SM_Billing_and_Send_Data_20141219
```

by using the variable in the table name.

I've been googling quite a bit and things seem to point to using dynamic SQL, but I've  never used it and not sure what the syntax would be to get the results I am looking for.

Comment: Can't you do something like `set @name = 'LM_SM_Billing_and_Send_Data_' + @date` and then `exec sp_rename 'LM_SM_Billing_and_Send_Data', @name`?

Comment: SQL doesn't do string interpolation. You seem to think it will look inside the `'LM_SM_Billing_and_Send_Data_@date'` and see the `@date` and do something with it. Nope.

Answer (score 6):

The issue you've ran into here, as John Saunders pointed out in his comment, SQL won't substitute the value of your variable into your parameter. (String interpolation)

Another issue you might run into, when trying to work around this problem, is concatenating in the procedure call. The following will also ***not*** work.

`exec sp_rename 'LM_SM_Billing_and_Send_Data', 'LM_SM_Billing_and_Send_Data_' + @date`

The reason the above will also error, is because a parameter can be either a variable, or a constant, not an expression as the above shows. If we declare `@myNewName`, and set the desired value into that variable, we can then pass that to the procedure.

Give this a try:

```
declare @date varchar(8)
set @date = convert( varchar(8), getdate(), 112)

declare @myNewName varchar(255) = 'LM_SM_Billing_and_Send_Data_' + @date

exec sp_rename 'LM_SM_Billing_and_Send_Data', @myNewName
```

This may be a good reference as one continues to work with SQL parameters: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189260(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: This worked perfectly for the rename, THANKYOU. later in the script I want to drop the table I have renamed with the date but, drop table @myNewName fails, error is  'expecting '.', ID or QUOTED_ID'. Any ideas?

Comment: @Sadie The link at the end of this comment may address your new problem, if not, I would suggest searching for dynamic sql, and  "t-sql drop table variable name". http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39627/how-to-drop-tables-using-a-variable-in-sql-server

Comment: thank you so much for your help, I found the solution; declare sql nvarchar(max)
set sql = 'drop table '+ myNewName
exec sp_executesql sql       the sql and myNewName are variables but this editor wouldn't let me add the @

Answer (score 0):

Use `Dynamic Sql` to append the variable to the new table name.

Use `select * into` syntax to copy the data from new old table to new table this part has to be done dynamically.

Then finally drop the old table

```
declare @date varchar(8),
set @date = convert( varchar(8), getdate(), 112)


set @sql ='select * into LM_SM_Billing_and_Send_Data_'+@date+' 
           from   LM_SM_Billing_and_Send_Data'

exec sp_executesql @sql

Drop table LM_SM_Billing_and_Send_Data
```