# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python

I am trying to run the simple code below：

```
from sys import argv
script, filename = argv
print ("erase %r") % filename
raw_input = ("?")
target = open(filename, 'w')
print ("truncate")
target.truncate()
print ("fline")
repeat3 = raw_input ('> ')
print ("write")
target.write(repeat3)
```

I  keep getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex9.py", line 9, in <module>
    repeat3 = raw_input ('> ')
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you did:

```
raw_input = ("?")
```

You assigned the name `raw_input` to the string `"?"`, so you can no longer call the function (instead, you're calling the string, which doesn't work).

Use a different name for your variable (though it looks like you're not even using it, so you could simply remove the offending line).

Comment: Thanks Thomas, commented that "?" out and works fine

Comment: @Sadie - please mark this answer as accepted by using the checkmark if it solved your question. Just saw that you did not do that on your other question either (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27574816/use-a-variable-in-the-table-name-when-renaming-a-table-in-sql) - maybe you`d like to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

You masked the `raw_input` function with `raw_input = ("?")`. You're looking for `user_input = raw_input("?")`, as you did correctly with `repeat3`.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> type(raw_input)
<type 'builtin_function_or_method'>
>>> raw_input = '?'
>>> type(raw_input)
<type 'str'>
```

What you did in your code was you overwrote what `raw_input` actually means. instead of keeping it as a function that gets user input, you turned `raw_input` into a regular variable that contains a `'?'` ( a string)

and Strings are not callable.

For example, if you run:

```
"?"('>')
```

You would get the same error, because its literally what you were trying to do.